# App crashes when trying to connect to bluetooth android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

I am trying to establish a bluetooth connection between my phone and a bluetooth device, but the app keeps crashing. By commenting, i have found out that the error is in the openBT() function. Can anyone help me out please?

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.UUID;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class PageOne extends Activity {

TextView myLabel;
TextView deviceFound;
Button openButton,closeButton;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pageone);
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    setUp();
    openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (openButton.getText().equals("Enable")) {
                findBT();
            }

            if(openButton.getText().equals("Start Connection")){
                System.out.println("here");

                try{
                    openBT();
                }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();};
            }
        }
    });

    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            closeBT();
            System.out.println("here too");
        }
    });

}
private void setUp() {
    openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    deviceFound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    setButtonText();



    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            setButtonText();

        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver (receiver, filter);
}   

private void setButtonText() {

    closeButton.setText("Disable bluetooth");
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        openButton.setText("Start Connection");
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth is enabled");
    } else {
        openButton.setText("Enable");
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth is disabled");
    }

}

private void findBT(){

    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
    }

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new
        Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

    } 

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            if(device.getName().equals("Hauwa")) 
            {
                mmDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    deviceFound.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");


}

private void closeBT(){
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        deviceFound.setText("bvnbvnvb");
    }
}

void openBT() throws IOException{

    final UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); 
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();


}



 }
```

and here is the logcat error

```
     01-07 02:55:23.189: W/dalvikvm(11382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401f0560)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382): java.lang.NullPointerException
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at com.example.BluetoothExample.PageOne.openBT(PageOne.java:147)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at       com.example.BluetoothExample.PageOne$1.onClick(PageOne.java:51)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2579)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at         android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9246)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
     01-07 02:55:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382): java.lang.NullPointerException
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at com.example.BluetoothExample.PageOne.openBT(PageOne.java:147)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at       com.example.BluetoothExample.PageOne$1.onClick(PageOne.java:51)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2579)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9246)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
     01-07 02:55:23.199: E/AndroidRuntime(11382):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: do you have the Bluetooth permission?

Comment: can u paste logcat logs

Comment: yes i did set the bluetooth permission.

Comment: are you sure that the mmDevice object is not null?

Comment: yes i am sure it isn't null.

Comment: Have you putted breakpoints in your code? It's very easy to find the objet that is `null` ..

Comment: i know that the error is from the second line in openBT(), which is  mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);. I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: are you sure that you have `mmDevice` not null? Are you sure you set `mmDevice` in findBT()
     if(device.getName().equals("Hauwa")) 
            {
                mmDevice = device;
                break;
            }

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you! i didnt call findBT() where mmDevice was decalred before calling openBT()

Comment: Added answer below, so you can accept it and mark question as answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure that you have `mmDevice` not null? Are you sure you set mmDevice in `findBT()`?

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
{
    for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
    {
        if(device.getName().equals("Hauwa")) 
        {
            mmDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My device is not null but crash,

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
String tmpS;
String targetS = "Hauwa";

if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
{
for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
{
    tmpS = device.getName() + "           ";
    tmpS = tmpS.substring(0,targetS.length());
    if(tmpS.equals(targetS)) 
    {
        mmDevice = device;
        break;
    }
}
```

you need to prevent the device name to be null. Even if your own device has name that is not null, the code could read other BLE device nearby that is null. You also need to prevent overflow at substring and equals functions,